# How to graph a polygon in 3D in r

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to graph a set of polygons in three dimensional space in R.  Each polygon is a (non-regular) k-simplex; that is, each side of the polygon is formed by a triangle. An example is given here:

```
             x1    y1   z1     x2    y2   z2    x3    y3   z3
triangle1  -2.59  8.44 6.00 -11.31 10.75 1.09 -2.59  8.44 6.00
triangle2   0.19  5.50 0.00  -3.66 10.27 0.61  0.19  5.50 0.00
triangle3 -11.31 10.75 1.09 -10.83 12.02 1.02 -2.73  9.75 1.23
triangle4 -10.83 12.02 1.02   0.19  5.50 0.00 -3.66 10.27 0.61
triangle5   0.19  5.50 0.00  -3.66 10.27 0.61  0.19  5.50 0.00
triangle6 -11.31 10.75 1.09 -10.83 12.02 1.02 -2.73  9.75 1.23
triangle7 -10.83 12.02 1.02  -2.59  8.44 6.00 -3.66 10.27 0.61
triangle8  -2.59  8.44 6.00  -2.73  9.75 1.23 -2.59  8.44 6.00
```

I have found packages in R that graph points (scatterplot3d) or functions (plot3D) in three dimensions, but I have not found one that graphs polygons.  There is a function in MATLAB (fill3) that generates the figure that I am looking for (example pictured below), however I am hoping to perform all of my data analysis (most of which has already been coded in R) in one platform.  Is there a package or a function in R that will generate figures of three dimensional polygons similar to those in MATLAB?

[Above data visualized as a three dimensional polygon, coded in MATLAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMeAc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The package you are looking for is `plot3D`, specifically the `surf3D` function. Example below:

```
x <- data.matrix(dat[,c("x1", "x2","x3")])
y <- data.matrix(dat[,c("y1", "y2","y3")])
z <- data.matrix(dat[,c("z1", "z2","z3")])


surf3D(x,y,z, colvar=NULL, col="blue", border="black", theta = 75, phi=45, bty="b2", zlim=c(0,6*13), xlim = c(-12,2), ylim=c(5,13))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  If I may, I have two follow up questions.  1) When I run the above code, I get a concave figure (i.e., it does not connect all of the triangles).  Do you know how to avoid this problem?  2) Is it possible to graph multiple polygons on the same figure using this function?